# Lap top get off when I separate charger

Tags: linux, hardware

I brought my lenovo-ideapad-320 to repair shop and changed my keyboard.
now when I separate my charger ,the lap top get off and doesn't get on without charger.
may is it related to long time being off?

Comment: your question is not about unix/linux, so it is off topic here

Answer (score 0):

The battery is dead or disconnected, or the charging circuitry in the laptop is not working. This could possibily be related to battery being disconnected for an **extremely** long time.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Jeremy Boden@ I took my lap top to change the battery but suddenly screen came black.After two days They told me your CPU is out .I know this is a serious problem and I fucked up!

Comment: Take it up with the repair shop! Changing a battery can't damage the CPU.

Comment: Jeremy Boden@I took it . The lap top get on but as I said just with charger . But Screen shows nothing . As You know I changed my keyboard and they told me the lap top doesn't have any problem that is belonged to hardware . Second repair shop told that my CPU is out . Do you think I should change the battery or It's a bad job!

Comment: Unless you can boot it with a charger plugged into the mains, its not worth worrying about a battery. Make these repair shops explain what they mean. "my CPU is out" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Jeremy Boden@In fact in my country most of repair shops are like scammers and I can't trust no one . I thought last repair shop even didn't look at my lap top .Its mean from saying that CPU is out was that the board is broken .But I say if my board is broken how my computer gets on .I don't know what should I do.